# Multidimensional Array Patterned Access

Tags: c, algorithm, math, multidimensional-array, output

So I have a multidimensional array of 4x16. I need to access it in a specific order, in 4x4 sections:

Array:

```
[  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ]

[  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ]

[  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ]

[  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ]
```

Access Directions:

```
 1.
    [00]
                [03]
            [02]
        [01]    

 2.
        [05]
    [04]
                [07]
            [06]

 3.
            [10]
        [09]
    [08]
                [11]

 4.
                [15]
            [14]
        [13]
    [12]

 5.
    Repeat for next 4x4 block
```

Resulting Access Pattern:

```
[00][05][10][15]
[04][09][14][03]
[08][13][02][07]
[12][01][06][11]

[16][21][26][31]
[20][25][30][19]
[24][29][18][23]
[28][17][22][27]

[32][37][42][47]
[36][41][46][35]
[40][45][34][39]
[44][33][38][43]

[48][53][58][63]
[52][57][62][51]
[56][61][50][55]
[60][49][54][59]
```

---

Now, I wanted to also access these in groups of four points, as shown above, and I also wanted to see what would be accessed beforehand, so I wrote this up:

```
#define MAX(x, y) (((x) > (y)) ? (x) : (y))
#define MIN(x, y) (((x) < (y)) ? (x) : (y))

void main (void) {
    int m;
    int n;

    const int h = 16;
    const int w = 4;
    int skip;

    int x, y;

    // ABCD
    // BCDA
    // CDAB
    // DABC
    // ABCD

    // 0 => [0,0][3,1][2,2][1,3]
    // 1 => [1,0][0,1][3,2][2,3]
    // 2 => [2,0][

    for (x = 0; x < h; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < w; y++) {
            m = w - ((x + y) % w);
            n = x + m;
            printf ("[%i,%i]", ((x + y)), n);
        }

        printf ("\n");

    }

    return;
}
```

---

When it runs, I wanted to get an output of:

```
[r,c][r,c][r,c][r,c]    (Group 0)
[r,c][r,c][r,c][r,c]    (Group 1)
...
```

ex:

Group 0 & 1

```
[0,0][3,1][2,2][1,3]
[1,0][0,1][3,2][2,3]
```

...

Group 5 & 6

```
[5,0][4,1][7,2][6,3]
[6,0][5,1][4,2][7,3]
```

and so on.

---

However, the output that I get is:

```
[0,4][1,3][2,2][3,1]
[1,4][2,3][3,2][4,5]
[2,4][3,3][4,6][5,5]
[3,4][4,7][5,6][6,5]
[4,8][5,7][6,6][7,5]
[5,8][6,7][7,6][8,9]
[6,8][7,7][8,10][9,9]
[7,8][8,11][9,10][10,9]
[8,12][9,11][10,10][11,9]
[9,12][10,11][11,10][12,13]
[10,12][11,11][12,14][13,13]
[11,12][12,15][13,14][14,13]
[12,16][13,15][14,14][15,13]
[13,16][14,15][15,14][16,17]
[14,16][15,15][16,18][17,17]
[15,16][16,19][17,18][18,17]
```

How can I get the output describe above instead?

---

Note:

I know I can use a lookup table, but afterwards I'm going to extend it to a 256x4096 multidimensional array, so a lookup table will be too big.

Comment: Nice question. Will your `256 x 4096` multidimensional array also consist of `4 x 4`s?

Comment: No, it will consist of 256x256 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC 4.8.2: gcc -Wall -Wextra main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  const int w = 4; // 256
  int i = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < w * w * 4 ; ++i) { // 16
    // Column calculation is trivial.
    int c = i % w;
    // Row calculation.
    int section_offset = (w * (i / (w * w)));
    int first_pass = ((w - i % w) % w);
    int shift = i / w;
    int r = (first_pass + shift) % w  + section_offset;
    printf("[%2i,%2i]", r, c);

    if (!((i + 1) % w)) {
      printf("    (Group %2i)\n", i / w); } }

  return 0; }
```

Output:

```
[ 0, 0][ 3, 1][ 2, 2][ 1, 3]    (Group  0)
[ 1, 0][ 0, 1][ 3, 2][ 2, 3]    (Group  1)
[ 2, 0][ 1, 1][ 0, 2][ 3, 3]    (Group  2)
[ 3, 0][ 2, 1][ 1, 2][ 0, 3]    (Group  3)
[ 4, 0][ 7, 1][ 6, 2][ 5, 3]    (Group  4)
[ 5, 0][ 4, 1][ 7, 2][ 6, 3]    (Group  5)
[ 6, 0][ 5, 1][ 4, 2][ 7, 3]    (Group  6)
[ 7, 0][ 6, 1][ 5, 2][ 4, 3]    (Group  7)
[ 8, 0][11, 1][10, 2][ 9, 3]    (Group  8)
[ 9, 0][ 8, 1][11, 2][10, 3]    (Group  9)
[10, 0][ 9, 1][ 8, 2][11, 3]    (Group 10)
[11, 0][10, 1][ 9, 2][ 8, 3]    (Group 11)
[12, 0][15, 1][14, 2][13, 3]    (Group 12)
[13, 0][12, 1][15, 2][14, 3]    (Group 13)
[14, 0][13, 1][12, 2][15, 3]    (Group 14)
[15, 0][14, 1][13, 2][12, 3]    (Group 15)
```

The insight, if there is any, is that `(i + X) % N` rotates a sequence [0..N-1], X times.

Comment: This seems to work, but could you explain the überlong calculation?

Comment: I have updated my solution. Perhaps it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

Let's observe your groups a little. One noticeable fact; each group starts off with a [row, 0]. Second fact, each subsequent element in groups attempt to go 1-up 1-right. Third fact, when they hit the ceiling, they fall to the bottom. And that's all:

- Start off with `[x, 0]`
- Go one right regardless
- Go one up if we aren't at the ceiling, otherwise three down

That being put in your loop:

```
...
for ( x = 0; x < h; x++ ) {
    m = x;  // start off with [x, ...
    n = 0;  // ... 0]
    for ( y = 0; y < w; y++ ) {
        printf( "[%i,%i]", m, n );
        m = ( m > x / w * w ) ? m - 1 : m + w - 1;
        // if not at ceiling, decrease m by 1, else increase by 3
        n++;    // increase n regardless
    }

    printf( "\n" );

}
...
```

I couldn't get a response to my question, so I'm sorry if you needed something more flexible than this. This will work out if you are going to use it on 8 `256 x 256`s, placed on top of each other.

### Edit

If you're unhappy with the branch, like you seem to be with your comment, then use the following assignment, as a replacement to the ternary assignment above:

```
...
m = ( m + w - 1 ) % w + x / w * w;
...
```

The thing above imposes a modulo operation with an offset `x / w * w`.

In maths, under `( mod w )` both the `m - 1` and `m - 1 + w` would describe the same value. In fact, you could as many `w`s as you want, they'd all be melting down.

The thing is, in C, `%` is not a modulo operator, but a remainder operator. So in the case when `m == 0` (which happens `w`-many times in the first block) `(m - 1) % w;` would be minus one, and wouldn't be brought above to `w - 1`.

So, I'm making use of the modulo operator identity in maths, which I've described above.

`x / w * w` only is for the offset. `... / w * w` brings `x` down to the closest multiple of `w`.

If you're going to use dimensions that are powers of 2 for sure, then you could use `(x & ~(w - 1))` which also would bring `x` down to the closest multiple of any `w` that is a power of 2. Like this:

```
m = ( m + w - 1 ) % w + (x & ~(w - 1));
```

It works by clearing off the bits to the right of the single bit that was being used to represent the `w`. For example, for `w = 256`:

```
// bit representation of w
0000 ... 0001 0000 0000

// of w - 1
0000 ... 0000 1111 1111

// of ~(w - 1)
1111 ... 1111 0000 0000
```

And `&`ing with that would clear those bits with `0`s for the `&`ee. The outcome would be `&`ee reduced to the closest multiple of 256.

Comment: Is there a way to use a modulo instead of a branch?

Comment: @haneefmubarak Well, of course, since in the end, what we do is a modulo operation with an offset. Use `m = ( m + w - 1 ) % w + x * w;` assignment instead. If you cannot see why it works, don't worry, I'll be putting an explanation along.

Comment: @haneefmubarak Sorry, apparently I've miswritten the offset here. It should be `... x / w * w;`, not directly `... x * w;`.

Comment: @haneefmubarak Oh well, elias apparently already had given this solution, even without the two of your variables, `m` and `n`. It looks a little obscure, but whatever

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what output you were looking for, but you can get the following output:

```
 [0, 0] [3, 1] [2, 2] [1, 3]
 [1, 0] [0, 1] [3, 2] [2, 3]
 [2, 0] [1, 1] [0, 2] [3, 3]
 [3, 0] [2, 1] [1, 2] [0, 3]
 [0, 0] [3, 1] [2, 2] [1, 3]
 [1, 0] [0, 1] [3, 2] [2, 3]
 [2, 0] [1, 1] [0, 2] [3, 3]
 [3, 0] [2, 1] [1, 2] [0, 3]
 [0, 0] [3, 1] [2, 2] [1, 3]
 [1, 0] [0, 1] [3, 2] [2, 3]
 [2, 0] [1, 1] [0, 2] [3, 3]
 [3, 0] [2, 1] [1, 2] [0, 3]
 [0, 0] [3, 1] [2, 2] [1, 3]
 [1, 0] [0, 1] [3, 2] [2, 3]
 [2, 0] [1, 1] [0, 2] [3, 3]
 [3, 0] [2, 1] [1, 2] [0, 3]
```

By using this code in place of your current for loop:

```
for (x = 0; x < h; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < w; y++) {
        m = w - (x + w - 1 - (y % w)) % w - 1;
        n = x;
        printf ("[%i,%i]", m, n);
    }

    printf ("\n");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that your pattern holds many beautiful symmetries, you can just pick the results like fruits of the conscious construction:

The element in the `i`th row of the `j`th column in the `k`th block is `(4*i+5*j)%16+16*k` (`i`, `j`, and `k` are all in the range [0,3]).

The `n`th group as you desire to see it in the output consists of the 4 pairs `(n/4*4+(n+4-i)%4, i)` for `i` being in [0,3] again.

```
const int h = 16;
const int w = 4;
int n,i;
for (n = 0; n < h; n++) {
    for (i = 0; i < w; i++) {
        printf ("[%i,%i]", (n/w)*w+(n+w-i)%w, i);
    }
    printf ("\n");
}
```

<s>Sorry, I'm not sure if the syntax is correct, I don't have any environment for c on my machine right now.</s> **EDIT:** It compiles fine and produces the desired output.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. I tried the code, and it worked after `i` and `n` got declared on the previous line.

Comment: Could you paste the entire code piece and also explain the complex expressions?

Comment: The only complex expression is the row coordinate, and its calculation is based on the fact, that group `n` uses row indexes in the range `[w*k, (w+1)*k-1]` for such `k` that `n` is inside that range. Furthermore, the row coordinate of the first element is exactly `n`, and from that on, each element's row coordinate is smaller by 1, until we reach the lower boundary of the range. In that case we continue from the upper boundary.